# VBA macro doesn't go to the end of file excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that puts 0 instead of blank rows there are more than 65000 of them everything works fine but problem is macro stops at line 62000 even if there is data on a next rows. Here is the code:

```
Sub QuickCull()
    On Error Resume Next
    Columns("a").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Columns("b").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Columns("d").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

    Dim col As Range
    Set col = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("E2", col).Resize(, 4)

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value = "" Then
           cell.Value = 0
        Else
           cell.Value = 1
        End If    
    Next cell

    Cells("J1").Activate

End Sub
```

It seems to me problem is with ranges but not sure at all. What could cause this?

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` then debug it again.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` may be needed for the first three code lines but should be reset to `On Error GoTo 0` immediately afterwards.

Comment: Done it but result is the same...

Comment: Try debug.print col?

Comment: re: *'even if there is data on a next rows'* But is there data on the next rows in column E? That is what sets the boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) does not accept the same style of cell address references that a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) does.

```
Cells("J1").Activate
'should be,
Range("J1").Activate
```

If columns E:H are having their values changed to 1 and their blanks changed to 0 then you can continue with the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) using [xlCellTypeBlanks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) and [xlCellTypeConstants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx).

```
Sub QuickCull()
    Dim col As Range, r As Range

    With Worksheets("data")   '<~~ you should know ehat worksheet you are on!
        On Error Resume Next
        .Columns("a").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        .Columns("b").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        .Columns("d").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

        Set col = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)
        Set r = .Range("E2", col).Resize(col.Row - 1, 4)

        r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) = 1
        r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = 0

        .Range("J1").Activate   '<~~ or .Cells(4, "J").Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Greate but problem remains the same